# Shadowing/Customizing parent theme's plugin in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin, mdxjs, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I am using the Gatsby theme [@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/tree/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog) for my own blog. The theme also has a parent core theme [@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/blob/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core/) which is making use of the [gatsby-plugin-mdx](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/) plugin.

In my own blog I'd like to change the plugin `gatsby-plugin-mdx`'s options such as setting

```js
options: {
  maxWidth: 960,
  quality: 90,
  linkImagesToOriginal: true, // set to true from false
}
```

I tried importing `gatsby-plugin-mdx` in my own blog's `gatsby-config.js` but it didn't work I'm getting errors parsing existing `.mdx` files.

Also trying to shadow the `gatsby-config.js` file of the core theme by creating `src/@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core/gatsby-config.js` with the same content but `linkImagesToOriginal: true` has no effects.

How can I change a parent theme's plugin's options?

The `gatsby-config.js` file of the core theme is as follows:

```js
const withDefaults = require(`./utils/default-options`)

module.exports = (themeOptions) => {
  const options = withDefaults(themeOptions)
  const { mdx = true } = themeOptions

  return {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
          name: options.postsPath,
          path: options.postsPath,
        },
      },
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
          name: options.pagesPath,
          path: options.pagesPath,
        },
      },
      mdx && {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
        options: {
          extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
          gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
            {
              resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
              options: {
                maxWidth: 960,
                quality: 90,
                linkImagesToOriginal: false, // want to set this to true
              },
            },
          ],
          plugins: [
            {
              resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
              options: {
                maxWidth: 960,
                quality: 90,
                linkImagesToOriginal: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
      `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    ].filter(Boolean),
  }
}
```

`gatsby-config.js` of my blog

```js
require(`dotenv`).config({
  path: `.env`,
})
const newsletterFeed = require(`./src/@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog/utils/newsletterFeed`)
const shouldAnalyseBundle = process.env.ANALYSE_BUNDLE

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteTitle: 'Kaan Uzdoğan',
    siteTitleAlt: `Kaan Uzdoğan - Personal Site`,
    siteHeadline: 'Kaan Uzdoğan - Personal Site',
    siteUrl: `https://kaanuzdogan.com`,
    author: `@kaanuzdogan`,
    siteLanguage: 'en',
    siteImage: '/banner.jpg',
    siteDescription: 'Personal Blog and Website of Kaan Uzdogan',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog`,
      // See the theme's README for all available options
      options: {
        feedTitle: 'Kaan Uzdoğan\'s Personal Site',
        navigation: [
          {
            title: `Blog`,
            slug: `/blog`,
          },
          {
            title: `About`,
            slug: `/about`,
          },
        ],
        externalLinks: [
          {
            name: `Twitter`,
            url: `https://twitter.com/kaanuzdogan`,
          },
          {
            name: `Instagram`,
            url: `https://www.instagram.com/kuzdogan`,
          },
          {
            name: `Github`,
            url: `https://github.com/kuzdogan`
          }
        ],
        formatString: 'DD MMMM YYYY'
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: newsletterFeed('Kaan Uzdoğan\'s Personal Site'),
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-disqus`,
      options: {
        shortname: `kaanuzdogan`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          process.env.GOOGLE_MEASUREMENT_ID, // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `minimal-blog - @lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog`,
        short_name: `minimal-blog`,
        description: `Typography driven, feature-rich blogging theme with minimal aesthetics. Includes tags/categories support and extensive features for code blocks such as live preview, line numbers, and code highlighting.`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#fff`,
        theme_color: `#6B46C1`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icons: [
          {
            src: `/android-chrome-192x192.png`,
            sizes: `192x192`,
            type: `image/png`,
          },
          {
            src: `/android-chrome-512x512.png`,
            sizes: `512x512`,
            type: `image/png`,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    shouldAnalyseBundle && {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2`,
      options: {
        analyzerMode: `static`,
        reportFilename: `_bundle.html`,
        openAnalyzer: false,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mailchimp',
      options: {
        endpoint: '<hiding the endpoint url>',
        timeout: 3500,
      },
    },
  ].filter(Boolean),
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `gatsby-config.js` that you are trying to modify (yours I mean)

Comment: I've edited the question to include the file. @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
module.exports = ()=> ({
  siteMetadata: {
    siteTitle: 'Kaan Uzdoğan',
    siteTitleAlt: `Kaan Uzdoğan - Personal Site`,
    siteHeadline: 'Kaan Uzdoğan - Personal Site',
    siteUrl: `https://kaanuzdogan.com`,
    author: `@kaanuzdogan`,
    siteLanguage: 'en',
    siteImage: '/banner.jpg',
    siteDescription: 'Personal Blog and Website of Kaan Uzdogan',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog`,
      // See the theme's README for all available options
      options: {
        feedTitle: 'Kaan Uzdoğan\'s Personal Site',
        navigation: [
          {
            title: `Blog`,
            slug: `/blog`,
          },
          {
            title: `About`,
            slug: `/about`,
          },
        ],
        externalLinks: [
          {
            name: `Twitter`,
            url: `https://twitter.com/kaanuzdogan`,
          },
          {
            name: `Instagram`,
            url: `https://www.instagram.com/kuzdogan`,
          },
          {
            name: `Github`,
            url: `https://github.com/kuzdogan`
          }
        ],
        formatString: 'DD MMMM YYYY'
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: newsletterFeed('Kaan Uzdoğan\'s Personal Site'),
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-disqus`,
      options: {
        shortname: `kaanuzdogan`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          process.env.GOOGLE_MEASUREMENT_ID, // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `minimal-blog - @lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog`,
        short_name: `minimal-blog`,
        description: `Typography driven, feature-rich blogging theme with minimal aesthetics. Includes tags/categories support and extensive features for code blocks such as live preview, line numbers, and code highlighting.`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#fff`,
        theme_color: `#6B46C1`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icons: [
          {
            src: `/android-chrome-192x192.png`,
            sizes: `192x192`,
            type: `image/png`,
          },
          {
            src: `/android-chrome-512x512.png`,
            sizes: `512x512`,
            type: `image/png`,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    shouldAnalyseBundle && {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2`,
      options: {
        analyzerMode: `static`,
        reportFilename: `_bundle.html`,
        openAnalyzer: false,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mailchimp',
      options: {
        endpoint: '<hiding the endpoint url>',
        timeout: 3500,
      },
    },
  ].filter(Boolean),
)}
```

According to [this guide from the great Jason Lengstorf](https://egghead.io/lessons/gatsby-configure-a-gatsby-theme-to-take-options) the `gatsby-config.js` needs to be turned into a function.

I don't know what the `.filter(Boolean)` is doing in this case, you can try removing it since I can't see where is defined.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try but AFAIK only themes can have gatsby configs as functions https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16013#issuecomment-514235110

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify the plugin thanks to the built in option `mdx` in the theme.

I set the `mdx: false` in my blog's `gatsby-config.js` which will disable the plugin in the core theme, and added the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` with new options in my blog's `gatsby-config.js`.